# How to use both dictionary and DataFrame with Mustache.jl rendering in Julia language?

Tags: julia, mustache

I am generating TeX files using a template and rendering that template using Mustache.

Firstly I have data in a DataFrame:

```
Row │ label │ score │ max   │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 3     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 4     │ 6     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 5     │ 7     │
```

and a dictionary:

```
student = Dict( "name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith");
```

I want to render a template such that both dictionary variables and DataFrame variables are replaced in the template. It is OK to use either a dictionary or a DataFrame but not both at the same time.

For example, the render works on a DataFrame only with the template 'tmpl' shown below:

```
tmpl = """

Your marks are:
\\begin{itemize}
  {{#:D}}
    \\item Mark for question {{:label}} is {{:score}} out of {{:max}}
  {{/:D}}
"""
rendered_marks = render(tmpl, D=df );
```

However, when I add variables such as :name or :surname from the 'student' dictionary, I get error messages:

```
marks_tmpl = """
Hello \\textbf{ {{:name}}, {{:surname}} }

Your marks are:
\\begin{itemize}
  {{#:D}}
    \\item Mark for question {{:label}} is {{:score}} out of {{:max}}
  {{/:D}}
\\end{itemize}

\\end{document}
"""
rendered_marks = render(tmpl, student, D=df );
```

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to mix `Dict` and keyword arguments. The easiest thing is to add the DataFrame to the dictionary.

First, create your `DataFrame`:

```
df = DataFrame(label=1:4, score=2:5, max=4:7)
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ label │ score │ max   │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 3     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 4     │ 6     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 5     │ 7     │
```

Next, reference your `DataFrame` in the dictionary for Mustache.jl rendering:

```
student = Dict( "name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith", "df" => df);

marks_tmpl = """
Hello \\textbf{ {{name}}, {{surname}} }

Your marks are:
\\begin{itemize}
{{#df}}
      \\item Mark for question {{:label}} is {{:score}} out of {{:max}}
{{/df}}
\\end{itemize}
"""
```

In this way, both dictionary and `DataFrame` variables are rendered:

```
julia> println(render(marks_tmpl, student))

Hello \textbf{ John, Smith }

Your marks are:
\begin{itemize}
      \item Mark for question 1 is 2 out of 4
      \item Mark for question 2 is 3 out of 5
      \item Mark for question 3 is 4 out of 6
      \item Mark for question 4 is 5 out of 7
\end{itemize}
```

I guess this is what you wanted?

Comment: So it appears that the dictionary can point to an external DataFrame and Mustache.jl will parse that DataFrame. That helps to keep all the info for Mustache.jl rendering in one tidy place.

Comment: Yes. Another approach would be e.g. to pass `DataFrame`, name and surname as three keyword arguments.

Comment: OK. So it is a list of arguments (including variables and DataFrames) or a single dictionary object containing these arguments as key => value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer, you could also have used an iterable to access the keys in the dictionary or alternatively named tuple:

```
tmpl = """
Hello {{#:E}}\\textbf{ {{:name}}, {{:surname}} }{{/:E}}

Your marks are:
\\begin{itemize}
  {{#:D}}
    \\item Mark for question {{:label}} is {{:score}} out of {{:max}}
  {{/:D}}
\\end{itemize}

\\end{document}
"""

using Mustache
using DataFrames

student = Dict( "name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith");
D = DataFrame(label=[1,2], score=[80,90])

Mustache.render(tmpl, E=(name="John",surname="Doe"),D=D, max=100)
```